# How to decrypt AES 256 CBC by javascrypt (Not Nodejs)?

Tags: javascript, encryption, aes

How can I decrypt an encrypted string like `dIwykUwOomuWcdw/QX/Aig==` in **AES 256 CBC** mode with the key `ds8am3wys3pd75nf0ggtvajw2k3uny92` and iv `jm8lgqa3j1d0ajus` as the picture below just with javascript (not Nodejs). I used to try with CryptoJs library but the result not like I expected.

[image]

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.2/rollups/aes.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.2/rollups/pbkdf2.js"></script>
<script>
    var str = 'dIwykUwOomuWcdw/QX/Aig==';
    var key = 'ds8am3wys3pd75nf0ggtvajw2k3uny92';
    var iv  = 'jm8lgqa3j1d0ajus';

    var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt("2730007809303", key, { iv: iv });
    var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted, key, { iv: iv});
    var base64_str = decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);
    console.log(atob(base64_str))
</script>
```

By the way, how can I convert input string `dIwykUwOomuWcdw/QX/Aig==` as `encrypted` object above ?

Comment: write your code in the post

Comment: Have you found proper answer to this? I am facing the similar problem. I am Encrypting in PHP and decrypting in JS. however the PHP is working fine and I can pass the encrypted file to this devglan and it decrypts it perfectly but on JS I am having issue 'Malformed UTF-8 data'. Let me know if you have found any solution to tis.

Comment: @HashirQadeer For a long time, but you can try Topaco's answer below for this issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code snippet is almost right. However, the key must *not* be passed as a string, otherwise CryptoJS will interpret it as a passphrase and generate the *actual* key and IV from it [[1]](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#the-cipher-input), with an insecure algorithm by the way. Instead, key and IV must be passed as `WordArray`, which is easily achieved using the encoders [[2]](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#encoders). Since key and IV are Utf8-strings in this example, they must be parsed with the Utf8-encoder. Then you will get the desired ciphertext of the web page. Be aware that `encrypt` returns a `CipherParams`-object that encapsulates the ciphertext among other data [[3]](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#the-cipher-output). Furthermore, you don't need the Base64-detour and should decode the decrypted data directly as UTF8-string:

```js
var key = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse('ds8am3wys3pd75nf0ggtvajw2k3uny92');     // Use Utf8-Encoder. 
var iv  = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse('jm8lgqa3j1d0ajus');                     // Use Utf8-Encoder

var encryptedCP = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt("2730007809303", key, { iv: iv });
var decryptedWA = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encryptedCP, key, { iv: iv});

var encryptedBase64 = encryptedCP.toString();                              // Short for: encryptedCP.ciphertext.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);
var decryptedUtf8 = decryptedWA.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);               // Avoid the Base64 detour.
                                                                           // Alternatively: CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.stringify(decryptedWA);  
console.log("Ciphertext (Base64)  : " + encryptedBase64)
console.log("Decrypted data (Utf8): " + decryptedUtf8);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.9-1/crypto-js.js"></script>
```

Note that the CBC-mode and PKCS7-padding are implicitly used, which are the default parameters of CryptoJS [[4]](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#block-modes-and-padding), so it is not necessary to specify them explicitly.

**Update:**

If the ciphertext is a string or a `WordArray`, a `CipherParams`-object must be created from it, because the `decrypt`-method expects an object of this type [[5]](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#the-cipher-output).  The entirety of all data encapsulated by the `CipherParams`-object can be most easily taken from its definition [[6]](https://github.com/brix/crypto-js/blob/develop/src/cipher-core.js). In the current case at least the ciphertext must be specified as `WordArray`. Optionally a formatter can be specified which determines the formatting strategy of `toString()` (if used):

```js
var key = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse('ds8am3wys3pd75nf0ggtvajw2k3uny92');     // Use Utf8-Encoder. 
var iv  = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse('jm8lgqa3j1d0ajus');                     // Use Utf8-Encoder

var ciphertext = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse('dIwykUwOomuWcdw/QX/Aig==');    // Use Base64-Encoder.       
var encryptedCP = CryptoJS.lib.CipherParams.create({
    ciphertext: ciphertext,
    formatter: CryptoJS.format.OpenSSL                                     // Optional, but required for encryptedCP.toString() 
});
var decryptedWA = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encryptedCP, key, { iv: iv});

var encryptedBase64 = encryptedCP.toString();                              // Short for: encryptedCP.ciphertext.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);
var decryptedUtf8 = decryptedWA.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);               // Avoid the Base64 detour.
                                                                           // Alternatively: CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.stringify(decryptedWA);  
console.log("Ciphertext (Base64)  : " + encryptedBase64)
console.log("Decrypted data (Utf8): " + decryptedUtf8);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.9-1/crypto-js.js"></script>
```

Comment: Many thanks for your detail explanation, but I have one more question: If I have only `encryptedBase64` string how can I convert `encryptedBase64` string to `encryptedCP` object ?

Comment: See the Update-section in my answer.

Comment: Great answer, this should have much more upvotes.

Comment: This works. Nice one

Comment: what is the solution without using the CryptoJS dependency?

Comment: @Taureon - Recommendations for libraries are [off topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) at SO, but take a look at this list for JavaScript crypto libraries: https://gist.github.com/jo/8619441#javascript-crypto-libraries

Comment: @Topaco I should've been clear that I was asking for a solution that uses ZERO 3rd party libraries. So that web developers don't have to add yet another questionably reliable dependency to their codebase for no reason.

Comment: @Taureon - If you are looking for *native* solutions: In (modern) browsers, [WebCrypto](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Crypto_API) is available, in the case of NodeJS use its [*crypto*](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html) module. For further questions or more details, please post a new question. Thx.